# Incorrect bar graph formatting in TeX

Tags: graph, tex

For some reason, two very simple Bar graphs look very different after compiling in tex. More precisely, on the right graph there is a distance from the columns to the lower border of the square. In the left graph, the columns are adjacent to the lower border of the square. I would like to change the left figure, to have the distance between the bottom of the square and the blue columns on the left chart, as it is implemented on the right. Do you know how to change the code of the left chart?

[A picture of the graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAnkP.png)

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.75,-1)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 179) (2, 122) (3, 79) (4, 59) (5, 49) (6, 205) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.75,-1)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 125) (2, 106) (3, 27) (4, 49) (5, 12) (6, 5) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of this code fragment